# Shared Hosting: How to Protect from abuse and ~ wildcard folder access? ex domain.com/~username

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, shared-hosting

Many times google alert me that abuse content or phising is installed in my website.

But looking about it there is nothing on my public folder on my server. I see that the referral url is on my domain, but to a trailing wildcard url like:
example.com/~alifer/paypal/index.php This on linux apache shared hosting is referred to a website and folder that is not mine!

So is there a way on a shared hosting server to disable or to protect my domain example.com not to accept ~ wildcard?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable mod_userdir.

Summary: This module allows user-specific directories to be accessed using the http://example.com/~user/ syntax.

sudo a2dismod mod_userdir

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: But Im on a sharing plain server not managed by me. Can I do this / have access?

Also could this lead not to serve well other shared websites in server folders?

Do you think I can ask my provider to do this?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Since you are on a shared server your host will have to disable it. I would defiantly ask your provider. There is a good chance they will disable it.